# Javascript return true if record is exist [Multiple]

Tags: javascript, mysql

I don't encounter any problem when only single data is in `assignedTo` however when multiple data is in `assignedTo` its validation no longer works, it is separated by the pipeline,

example of single data by `assignedTo`:

```
123456
```

for multiple data of `assignedTo`:

```
123456|789101
```

current code

```
    hasExistingEvent: (assignedTo) => {
        var assignes = assignedTo.replace(/\|/g, ",")
        return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            .....("SELECT exp_fAssignedTo FROM Event WHERE exp_fAssignedTo LIKE '%" + assignes + "%'", 100, function(a){
                return !resolve(a.length ==0)
            })
        })
    },
    validatedUserExistsEvent: async(data) => {
        var {  assignedTo } = data
        var hasExisting = await _data.hasExistingEvent(assignedTo);
        console.log(hasExisting)
        return hasExisting;
    },
```

the `exp_fAssignedTo` field is collection of ids , Its a string of ids. Separated by coma

data from database

[image]

I don't know how or what logic to do

Comment: I don't think `LIKE '%123456|789101%'` is valid SQL

Comment: Are the values in the database also delimited by a pipe character?  (If so, the data model is wrong.)  Does any record exist with the exact (sub)string value you're looking for?  Or are you trying to find records with values present in a list of input values?  It's not really clear what specifically you're trying to do, only that multiple values concatenated into a single delimited string is most certainly the wrong data structure.

Comment: @Apolo it is. It's searching for the string `123456|789101` in any position (with wildcards before and after)

Comment: yes you were right, my current code here will work on single data, my problem is I don't know how to make the logic work when the `assignedTo` is multiple

Comment: @VLAZ yeah right but then, as David mentioned, if there's ids stored like that the issue is probably the DB design. OP is probably looking for a way to search multiple ids inside Assigned_To_Ids.

Comment: @kaito providing some sample data (especially the format of Assigned_To_Ids will help answer your question

Comment: @David I'm looking for a way to search for multiple ids inside the Assigned_To_Ids

Comment: @Apolo okay, please wait.

Comment: Also, I hope you have input sanitization. What would happen if `validatedUserExistsEvent` is called with this ? `{assignedTo:";DROP TABLE Event;"}`

Comment: @Apolo I have a field name `exp_fAssignedTo` is collection of ids , Its a string of ids. Separated by coma

Comment: @Apolo I just posted my record on database, please see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243823/discussion-between-kaito-and-apolo).

Comment: @Apolo have you seen my updated question?